# Spring MVC redirect cutting JSESSIONID in URL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session-variables, http-redirect

I'm trying to redirect from a Spring MVC Controller in my Webapplication to an external URL given by a certain payment service. The URL Pattern is:

```
https://xxz.et/xyz/abc.jsp;jsessionid=<SessionID>.worker11?FRONTENDLANGUAGESELECTED=de
```

What the browser Address bar shows is:

```
https://xxz.net/xyz/abc.jsp?FRONTENDLANGUAGESELECTED=de
```

and the payment service returns Session Timeout. If I enter the complete URL manually, it works. I tried redirecting either by httpResponse.sendRedirect() or making the method return redirct:.

Comment: Can you post some code? Specifically where you are making the actual redirect. Form where are you getting the sessionId value?

Comment: The whole url including sessionId is provided by the payment provider.  I realised it now without redirecting, yet I still don't understand why it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. This is because you use servlets 2.4, you can change this in you file: webapp.xml for use Servlets 3.0.

Use this xml config header:

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

I hope I could have helped you. a greeting